# Blazor. NavLink is not working in a foreach block when clicking multiply times

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

I created list of `NavLink`,  this is only one difference between them, dynamic parameter `Id`

```
<div>
    @foreach (var service in pageGlobal.Person.Services)
    {
        var link = $"service_description/{service.Identifier}";
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
           <li class="nav-item px-3">
              <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@link">
                   @service.Name
               </NavLink>
           </li>
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

And it works only if I click first time(no matter what NavLink item it works properly).

[image]

Click to the next link - url is changed but nothing happens.

[image]

Code of the `ServiceDescription.razor`

```
@page "/service_description/{Id:int}"
@using Site.Data
@using Site.ViewModels
@inject StartUpService page

@if (service != null)
{
    <div> <h3>Service Name - @service.Name</h3> - <h4>@service.Description</h4>  </div>
}

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    PageGlobal pageGlobal;
    Service service;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        pageGlobal = await page.GetPageGlobalAsync();
        service = pageGlobal.Person.Services.Where(e => e.Identifier == Id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

How can I force client reload `ServiceDescription.razor` with a new parameter using `NavLink` functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is caused by `OnInitializedAsync`. For `OnInitializedAsync`, it will be called only when the component is invoked when the component is ready to start.

If you want to change `service` based on parameter, you should use `OnParametersSetAsync` like below:

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    pageGlobal = new PageGlobal
    {
        Person = new Person()
        {
            Services = new List<Service>(){
                new Service{ Identifier = 1, Name = "Test1", Description = "D1" },
                new Service{ Identifier = 2, Name = "Test2" , Description = "D2" },
                new Service{ Identifier = 3, Name = "Test3", Description = "D3"  }
            }
        }
    };
    service = pageGlobal.Person.Services.Where(e => e.Identifier == Id).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

You could check [ComponentBase](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c74e9efd0e6ea5b4d6737d23b92042772a50a249/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs)